# Trying to get descriptive/summary statistics by 2 levels/categories

Tags: stata

I have a bit of a rudimentary question. I am trying to get descriptive statistics into word/excel/txt format for my data which is made up of 5 repeated cross section surveys with probability weights [pw=weight_hh]

I want to get the descriptives into this format (attached)

[image: Table Format]

I have the population divided into 2 groups and the years represent the survey rounds. At the moment I am using the means command to either obtain the descriptives for each round separately or each group separately- but not both at one go. Moreover I used both tabout and outreg2 with means to export data and both commands save a file with a table but the tables are blank?

I am relatively new to programming on Stata so I apologize if the question isn't very clear. Any direction on this will be greatly appreciated.

This is what I'm trying at the moment.

```
global outcomes marital male age 

foreach var in $outcomes {

  levelsof year, local (year)

    levelsof group, local (group)
    foreach g of local hhgrp {

qui foreach r of loc year {

        qui mean `var' if round==`r' & hhgrp==`g' & keep_main==1 [pw=hhwt]
        matrix N`var'=e(N)
        matrix m`var'=e(b)
        matrix sd`var'=e(V)
        matmap sd`var'sd`var', m(sqrt(@))
        matrix `r'`var'`g'= N`var', m`var', sd`var'
        matrix rownames `var'=`var'

}
}
}
```

But its only producing one matrix per variable that is 3 in total. I was hoping it would produce 10 per variable that is 30 in total

That is

Marital->10 matrices-> 5 survey years x 2 groups

Age ->10 matrices-> 5 survey years x 2 groups

Male ->10 matrices-> 5 survey years x 2 groups

Cross posted here: http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/990246-basic-question-about-descriptive-statiistics

Comment: I doubt you'll get an answer in this forum as this is a statistics and probability forum, not a programming forum.

Comment: There's no data and no code, so this problem is not reproducible. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking on how to post a good question, specially http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: I am sorry if the question wasnt very clear. I've added a link to the code.

Comment: You refer to a local `hhgrp` but it seems you never define it. The user-written program `matmap` should be documented as such. Most importantly, this is not reproducible without users creating their own data files with such data.

Comment: I'm sorry Nick, I didn't quite understand your comment. However hhgrp in my sample consists of 2 groups that define my sample, for example 1=Christian 0=Non Christian

Comment: Look again at the code above to see that you did not define it. You fixed the problem in your answer. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you want. A table similar to the one shown in the image can be produced with `tabstat` (`weights` are allowed but not used in the example):

```
clear
set more off

*----- example data -----

sysuse auto

*----- what you want -----

label define lblrep78 1 ", rep 1" 2 ", rep 2" 3 ", rep 3" ///
    4 ", rep 4" 5 ", rep 5"

label values rep78 lblrep78    

egen groupv = group(foreign rep78), label

tabstat price weight, stats(mean semean) by(groupv) nototal
```

Your code however implies that you want matrices. Which one is it?

Comment: Unfortunately, as these are survey data, `tabstat` won't produce correct standard errors.

Comment: Thanks to @Steve Samuels for pointing out a key aspect I overlooked.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies everyone. I tried `tabstat`, but it doesn't allow `pWeights`. I eventually went with this code and got close to what I wanted

```
outreg, clear
global outcomes age yrs_ed marital male  
foreach var in $outcomes {
levelsof round, local (round)
levelsof hhgrp, local (hhgrp)
foreach g of local hhgrp {
qui foreach r of loc round {
        qui mean `var' if round==`r' & hhgrp==`g' & keep_main==1 [pw=hhwt]
        matrix N`var'=e(N)
        matrix m`var'=e(b)
        matrix sd`var'=e(V)
        matrix `var'`g'`r'= m`var', sd`var', N`var'

}
}
}

outreg, clear
frmttable, clear
foreach var in $outcomes {
levelsof hhgrp, local (hhgrp)
foreach g of local hhgrp {

mat `var'`g'= `var'`g'90\ `var'`g'95\ `var'`g'00\ `var'`g'05\ `var'`g'10
}
}
foreach var in $outcomes {
levelsof hhgrp, local (hhgrp)
foreach g of local hhgrp {
qui frmttable using "$output\Output1.doc", sdec (2\2\0\2\2\0\2\2\0\2\2\0\2\2\0) substat(2) statmat(`var'`g')/*
*/ title("Individual Statistics") coljust(l;c) varlabels ctitles("", `var' \ "", `g') /*
*/ rtitles (Mean \ SD \ N \ Mean \ SD\ N\ Mean \ SD \ N \ Mean \ SD \ N \ Mean \ SD \ N ) merge
}
}
```

Comment: Good that you got closer to a solution, but to be of much else to anyone else this needs (1) an example with reproducible data (2) explanations of which user-written programs need to be installed and from where `outreg`, `frmttable` (3) commentary and results, talking readers through what is wanted and what happens. Otherwise this is just "here is my code and it works".

Comment: You  displayed means and standard errors will be incorrect for survey data, as your code ignores the sample design. I can't test this,  since you did not provide an example with accessible data, but I expect that the following will work: 1) `svyset` the data; 2) in your code replace `qui mean` by `qui svy:mean`.